# What does the little number under "favorite" star on questions mean?

Tags: support

When I look at a question with more than a few votes, I see a little number underneath the question's votes, just under the "favorite" star.

There's no pop-up text on it, and no label. Just ... a number ...

[image]

What does it mean, please? I've posted a question with "5" on it, and I don't know whether to smile or duck!

Comment: Those many users have favorited it.

Comment: Oh! Ok - so it's a really good thing! Wonderful!

Comment: You can go to [questions in profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5851520/susanw?tab=questions) and hover on the star and see the tooltip. _this question has been favorited by 5 users_

Comment: Fantastic - hmm, tool-tip should be on main page too, I guess. Oh dear, I'm getting downvotes ... I can delete this question, but I couldn't find explanation elsewhere... is this a dupe?

Comment: @SusabW downvotes on meta don't cost you rep. No need to delete :). And, while likely good, some people favorite bad posts (to close vote the next day once their quota refreshed, for instance). I wouldn't say that this is the jorm, but it does happen

Comment: @Patrice Ok, thanks for explanation! And ... hmm, so my favorites may be assassins hovering, waiting for my shields to be down... fine, I'll hold my breath till later in the week to see how it works out. Not literally, obviously...

Comment: @SusanW i don't think that favoriting bad content is the norm at all. Just mentioning it so you know it's not always black & white :). Don't stress with it :) from a quick glance, your questions on SO look fine ^^

Comment: @Patrice :-) No problem, I'm all relaxed... Thanks again!

Comment: @NathanOliver aha, that's what I was looking for! Hmm, problem is, it's unfindable without knowing that it's a "favorites"-related thing. I had "little number under favorites star" in my search string and alas, no hits.

Comment: You thought about it too hard.  I just searched *number under star* and it was the second result ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, seems that way :-) 
Anyway, I don't care - I've got favorites! Champagne all round!!

Comment: @Patrice ... and just to follow up - I _still_ have favorites, and although it went on hold that day, it was reopened and came back to life again. I reckon I'm safely though the fire now. More champagne required! :-)